# Laravel change collection attributes name

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-collection

How would you change the attributes from a collection?
So the return is a Collection of Models with changed attributes, and not a Collection of arrays.

The things is, I would like to make some kinda of translation presenter, so when I get the collection I could dd($collection) and instead of 'name' it would show 'nome', also using response()->json($collection) would show the changed named.

so something like $presenterNames = ['name' => 'nome', 'id' => 'identificador']; and the names that aren't here would call normally.

```
Collection {#213 ▼
    #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => Category {#215 ▼
            +timestamps: false
            #fillable: array:2 [▶]
            #connection: "mysql"
            #table: "categories"
            #primaryKey: "id"
            #keyType: "int"
            +incrementing: true
            #with: []
            #withCount: []
            #perPage: 15
            +exists: true
            +wasRecentlyCreated: false
            #attributes: array:3 [▼
            "id" => 1
            "name" => "categoria1"
            "slug" => "categoria1"
            ]
            #original: array:3 [▶]
            #changes: []
            #casts: []
            #dates: []
            #dateFormat: null
            #appends: []
            #dispatchesEvents: []
            #observables: []
            #relations: []
            #touches: []
            #hidden: []
            #visible: []
            #guarded: array:1 [▶]
            #slugOptions: null
        }
        1 => Category {#219 ▶}
    ]
}
```

so basically I would like to change

```
#attributes: array:3 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "categoria1"
    "slug" => "categoria1"
]
```

to this

```
#attributes: array:3 [▼
    "identificador" => 1
    "nome" => "categoria1"
    "slug" => "categoria1"
]
```

Dinamicaly by using a assoc array.

Comment: why you want to change this and why not you change from db?

Comment: because I would like to mantain the database using english conventions, but I would like to be able to translate the key if needed, its really easy to do using fractal, but fractal is only for array or json responses, but I would like to still use the collection if possible if that response isn't array or json.

Answer (score 1):

Solution :

In your Model add below code.

```
  protected $appends = ['nome'];

  public function getNomeAttribute(){

    return $this->attributes['name'];

 }
```

You can access it  by querying $modelObj->nome;

Do the same for all needed attributes.

This will also reflect in your JSON response.

Thanks

Reference : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Comment: wouldn't this be bad for performance? instead of changing directly before making the collection, iterating to change each one sounds a bit heavy performance, and this returns an array and not the collection back, so I can't really use the collection methods or any other after maping it, so I would also not be able to call $something->relationship->something

Comment: Can you please specify the input type & return type. You can modify the above code so that it will return array using toArray().

Comment: basically I just want to change the collection attributes, so return is still going to be a collection, something like \App\Category:all(); returns a collection of categories, I want that collection to have the attributes changed based on what I specified to change, it will work just like the collection you get from all() but just another names for the attributes.

Comment: The above code will return the collection. Check return type. Can you elaborate your requirement so that i can suggest something else.

Comment: Collection {#220 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      "identificador" => 1
      "nome" => "categoria1"
      "slug" => "categoria1"
    ]
    1 => array:3 [▶]
  ]
}

it does return a collection, but inside of it is an array, and not a collection of models, I will change my question to specify that It needs to maintain what kinda of collection it is.

Comment: not right now, I think I get how I would do that using the setAttribute() from the hasAttribute trait, but don't know yet, if unseting the old values is a good thing or change appending the new values is good enough, because the collection would be bigger if it was the case.

Comment: is there a way to make this dinamyc? that is my main problem, I know about mutators, but they need to be writen, and that would be really hard if there is more then 1 translation, so I was thinking about using the __set and __get magic method.

Comment: It depends upon your use.